# "Würde" oder Konjunktiv II, wenn der Konjunktiv dem Indikativ entspricht?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive

Bei manchen Verben entspricht ja der Konjunktiv I dem Indikativ, sprich es ist keine Unterscheidung möglich, z. B. in dem folgenden Satz:

> Er sagte, sie nehmen teil.

Wenn ich aber trotzdem betonen möchte, dass ich eine Aussage *wiedergebe* (im Beispielssatz ist das durch den vorangestellten Nebensatz natürlich eindeutig, aber das ist ja nicht immer der Fall), welche der folgenden Möglichkeiten ist dann korrekt?

- Ausweichen auf den Konjunktiv II:

  > Er sagte, sie nähmen teil.
- Eine Konstruktion mit "würde":

  > Er sagte, sie würden teilnehmen.

Und welche dieser Optionen auch korrekt ist, ist diese dann eine **Möglichkeit** oder eine **Pflicht**, wenn der Konjunktiv I dem Präsens entspricht?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beides ist zulässig. Die erste Lösung ist der grammatikalisch korrekte(re) Fall, die Variante mit *würde* ist umgangssprachlicher und generell mittlerweile wohl die dominante Variante (zunehmend auch in der informellen Schriftsprache). Der ursprüngliche Satz mit *nehmen* wäre aber zumindest in der gesprochenen Sprache absolut in Ordnung, da hier der Kontext die grammatikalische Ambivalenz aufklärt.

Comment: Hm, im Gesprochenen und informeller Schreibweise wird sicher beides verstanden, aber was ist mit akademischen Texten? Hatte immer den Eindruck, die Konstruktion mit "würde" sei zwar gebräuchlich, aber streng genommen nicht erlaubt ... will in meiner Hausarbeit keine solchen Fehler machen °ω°

Comment: Die alte Regel »wenn ist würde-los« ist seit Jahrzehnten schon überholt, und auch in anderen Konstruktionen ist der Ersatz eines echten Konjunktivs durch eine Würde-Phrase in praktisch allen Bereichen gang und gäbe. Denn es gilt auch hier was generell für Sprachen gilt: Nicht die Regeln geben vor was richtig und was falsch ist, sondern der tatsächliche Gebrauch gibt vor was man als Regel formulieren kann. Anders gesagt: Wenn der tatsächliche Gebrauch nicht mit einer bestehenden Regel übereinstimmt, ist nicht der tatsächliche Gebrauch falsch, sondern die Regel ist veraltet.

Comment: Aber nur weil die Regel veraltet ist, heißt es nicht, dass sie nicht einen besseren Eindruck hinterlässt. In meinen schriftlichen Arbeiten würde `würde` nur als Konjunktivform von `werden` auftauchen; für alles andere würde ich die entsprechende ein-Wort-Form nehmen. (*X behauptete, Z nehmen teil* oder *nähmen Z wirklich teil, müsste man auch …*). Wichtig ggf auch noch zu erwähnen: Es ist stets nur eine **Möglichkeit**, keine Pflicht!

Comment: Ok, danke Euch allen!

Comment: @Jan: Das ist eine Stil-Frage. Wenn du immer den Konjunktiv anstelle einer Würde-Konstruktion verwendest, werden dich die einen möglicherweise für belesen und gebildet halten, andere aber vielleicht für verstaubt und angehoben, was nicht unbedingt ins Bild von »einen besseren Eindruck hinterlassen« passt. Ich glaube, dass man seinen Stil ganz einfach an das Umfeld anpassen sollte. Keine der beiden Möglichkeiten ist die einzige und alleinige Optimal-Variante.

Comment: Regeln sind dazu da, eine gewisse Logik und Konsistenz im Sprachgebrauch und damit auch eine möglichst große Kommunikationsreichweite sicherzustellen, vor allem in einem riesigen und sehr inhomogenen Sprachraum wie dem deutschen. Der Sprachgebrauch der Mehrheit tendiert zu Einfachheit und Ökonomie, was in Ordnung ist, aber, und das ist ein eindeutiges Manko, nicht unbedingt zur Präzision. Denn dieser Sprachgebrauch ergibt sich mehrheitlich aus den Kommunikationsbedingungen gesprochener Sprache, die entscheidend anders sind als die der schriftlichen Kommunikation. Auch in vielen...

Comment: ...Diskussionen hier auf Stack.Exchange vermisse ich die klare Unterscheidung dieser beiden Kategorien. Vor allem, wenn einem die Sprache wichtig ist, was ich für die Teilnehmenden hier voraussetze, sollte man Regeln nicht ohne Weiteres einem diffusen "mehrheitlichen Sprachgebrauch" opfern. Es kann dann in manchen Fällen als Konsequenz nämlich passieren, dass man mangels sprachlicher Differenzierung und Transparenz nur noch das ausdrücken kann, was der andere ohnehin schon weiß.